# PHP get Value from another file

Tags: php

I have two files

```
Folder1/addmember.php

Folder2/config.php
```

now I'm trying to get the values of the radio from file 1

**addmember.php**

```
<div class="col">
        <label><?=$lang['newmember']['gender']?>:</label>
        <label class="pt-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" /> female</label>
        <label class="pt-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="2" /> male</label>
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?=$lang['submit']?></button>*
```

**config.php**

```
*include '../Folder1/addmember.php';
        
$answer = $_POST['gender'];  
if ($answer == "1") {          
      
}
else {
    
}*
```

Comment: How is the form data being posted?  Is it a standard `<form>` element, and if so what PHP script does it POST to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form and point to the config.php, to get that value.
For example

```
<form action="config.php" method="post">
Male: <input type="radio" name="gender"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and in config.php you can get the value from $_POST["gender"]